# What license needed to deploy SharePoint 2013 Apps?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am in the process of designing a SharePoint 2013 App for my company and i want to know what SharePoint license type is required, if i want to deploy this App On Premise for any customer, what type of license he will need? will it be the same as normal SharePoint solutions or this will be different?

The App will be provider hosted with back end of MVC.Net.

Another question, can i run the App alone without SharePoint at all if i abstracted the security and permissions part? i want to do this if the client doesn't have a SharePoint installed, so i can give him the app and run it as a normal MVC site.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A a full list of [SharePoint features availability across on-premise](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819267.aspx#bkmk_FeaturesOnPremise) is available on msdn

If you want to use the apps you will need as least SharePoint Server 2013 Standard CAL

If you want to run the app without SharePoint. I guess you will deliver a standalone MVC application not an app.